# Can we swap two numbers in C or C++ without passing pointers or references to the swap function?

Tags: c++, c

I have been asked this question once or twice in interviews. I am not sure whether it's possible or not. Maybe structures in C are a way out? Can anyone elaborate on this further?

Comment: Are you asking about C, or C++? The answer is likely different for each language.

Comment: You have to elaborate. Who says you need a function? Does a struct containing a reference count?

Comment: This doesn't sound well-specified enough. The interview question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Interviewer is probably trying to ask about the XOR swap trick. Stupid trick; stupid question; stupid interviewer.  You don't want to work there.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but talking about a "function" doesn't make sense then.

Comment: Considering he mentioned references, it's probably c++. Also, the XOR trick won't work because the variables are copied so it still won't swap anything. The question makes perfect sense, the answer is just no.

Comment: Though I suppose if you assign the pointers to global variables, and the swap function accesses those global variables, you're technically not passing pointers (directly) to the swap function. :)

Comment: @Pubby isn't a struct just a pointer to the beginning of it?

Comment: @GriffinHeart What? A pointer to a struct refers to the start, but they can still be passed "by value".

Comment: I believe the expression in English here is : ( without pointers) and ( without referring to the function "swap" )

Comment: Huh, I would say that @BRPocock "debugged" the question as being poorly worded except that "without passing pointers" would then be missing something since I would then ask: pass to what? The answer, of course, is "to the swap function".

Comment: It says closed as duplicate by me.  But I didn't choose close as duplicate.  It's certainly not a duplicate of the suggested question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the two values are inside a structure, then you can use the function's return value instead of passing by reference:

```
struct twoNumbers {
  int first;
  int second;
};

struct twoNumbers swapNumbers(struct twoNumbers src)
{
  int tmp = src.first;
  src.first = src.second;
  src.second = tmp;
  return src;
}

/* ... */

struct twoNumbers s = { 5, 42 };

s = swapNumbers(s);
```

...though even then it's probably more practical to use pointers.

Comment: THIS. Good job, an actual legitimate answer to what otherwise seemed an impossible question!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Oh yes he also added no global variables or Xor. But that does not apply here.

Comment: How about returning a `std::pair<int, int>`? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the swap function is actually a macro, it isn't possible. If you aren't passing by pointer or reference, then you're passing by value which means it's going to pass a copy rather than the value itself, so there is no way you can affect the variables in the scope of the caller because the values are copied.

Any swapping you do there, even using the addresses will result in not affecting whatsoever the state of the variables in the scope of the caller.

Comment: I don't believe the question refers to being inside a function or other scope?

Comment: "without passing pointers or reference to the swap function". In other words, you are passing two values to a swap function by value, and trying to swap them. It isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need a function to make the swap, and the function can not accept references or pointers, I can only think of one way, which is totally non-portable, and probably won't work consistently:

The swap function would have to examine the stack to find the return address of the calling code.  Then it would have to loop backwards, dissasembling the code leading up to the call, identifying the instructions which push the arguments onto the stack (or put them into the argument registers, depending on the platform's standard calling convention), and identifying the memory locations the arguments were loaded from.   You can then perform a swap of the values in those memory locations.   You should probably also to fixup the intermediate registers used to transfer the values, if they weren't overwritten before the call.

As I said, totally non-portable and completely error prone.   But if you understand the machine architecture and the nominal compilation output well enough to describe how you would do it, you will probably impress your interviewer.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with C or C++ languages.

Comment: All it takes is a line or two of inline assembly to get the stack pointer. Reading the instruction set can be in C, the dissassembly can be written in C, the memory acccess can be written in C, ...   And it relies on knowing the C or C++ convention for function calls and argument passing.

Comment: @AShelly: Knowing the instruction set (and the very term _instruction set_) and how to get the stack pointer (and the term _CPU stack_ or _stack pointer_) has nothing to do with C and C++ languages. You might embed the machine code for the whole OS into some static byte array and run this code with your C program. Then you'd have pure C program and it would be a working OS but still it wouldn't be the OS written in C. So even though your comment statements are correct your answer still has nothing to do with C or C++ languages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Here is the code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
// Want to swap x and y.
{
  int tmp = x;
  x = y;
  y = tmp;
}
// They have now been swapped. No function calls. No pointers. No references.
```

Comment: He said from the swap function. That's not a function.

Comment: I'm not calling the swap function with pointers or references. So this still answers the OP's question.

Comment: He said, "without reference to the swap function." This code fragment has no references to "swap" anywhere in it.

Comment: "without passing pointers or reference to the swap function". I am not passing pointers or references to a swap function. I see no problem with what I posted, as it DOES answer his question with compliance to his specs.

Comment: It doesn't say "A SWAP FUNCTION" it says "THE SWAP FUNCTION". So where's THE swap function?

Comment: You guys are not negating the question properly. Take `without passing pointers to foo`. This is `not (pass pointers to foo)`. Not even using foo satisfies this predicate. Come on guys. Bone up on your first order logic.

Comment: +1, this code is definitely not passing pointers or references to anything, in particular to the swap function. I wonder how many people, when they see the "do not stick your hands out of the window" sign on a train, try to find something else to stick their hands out of. I mean, common, the sign does mention both "hands" and "sticking", thus making it mandatory to stick your hands out of something!

Comment: I actually thought of this answer the first time I read the question. As I was reading through the comments, I realized I misunderstood the question, but good job taking a step back and giving this answer!

Answer (score 1):

yes! piece of cake!

given the problem statement as is....can do it without passing anything to the swap function! its simple to do like :-

```
int first;
int second;


void swap()
{
   int temp = first;
   first = second;
   second = temp;
}
```

Comment: thats the problem with some of those interview questions,  some you can't solve by programming 'nicely'

Answer (score 1):

They didn't say you must call `swap` only once:

```
int swap(bool do_swap, int x = 0, int y = 0)
{
    static int x_;
    static int y_;
    if (do_swap) {
        x_ = y;
        y_ = x;
        return x_;
    }
    return y_;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 42;
    x = swap(true, x, y);
    y = swap(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution if we need to exchange two int16

```
uint32_t swap16(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    return (x << 16 | y);
}

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t x, y;
    uint32_t res;

    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    res = swap16(x, y);
    x = res & 0xffff;
    y = (res >> 16) & 0xffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//Swapping two numbers without using function arguments
//please correct me in case of any errors
//using stack (stack is ussed for storing local variables)push and pop concepts //here

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun_1();
void main()
{
    int a,b;
    a = 2;
    b = 3;
    printf("values of a & b before : %d %d ", a, b);
    fun_1();
    printf("values of a & b after : %d %d ", a, b);
}
void fun_1()
{
    int temp, *ptr;
    ptr = &temp;
    ptr--;
    temp = *ptr;
    ptr = ptr-1;
    ptr--;
    *ptr = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use arrays as in arrays it's no necessary to pass values with `&` or with a pointer

like

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(int  a[])
{
    int t=a[0];
    a[0]=a[1];
    a[1]=t;
}


int main()
{

int a[2];

cin>>a[0]>>a[1];

swap(a);

cout<<a[0]<< "  "<<a[1];
    
}
```

Iam not using any pointer

Iam not even using `&` operator

Answer (score -1):

You can use a struct/class that contains both number to swap, but that's kinda silly.
What you could use is a macro. (maybe the answer they wanted?)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not really sure about your original question, but it looks like you need something like:

```
num1 = num1 + num2;
num2 = num1 - num2;
num1 = num1 - num2;
```

Comment: This will not swap the variables at the scope of the caller.

Comment: That's an an answer to the question "how do you swap without a temporary?", not this question.

Comment: there's no requirement to "call a function" in the question

Answer (score -2):

This is an old trivia question. **frustration**

They're asking if you know the XOR-swap trick.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

It also implies (to me) you're being interviewed by someone who's either 20 years out of date, or is just an *expletive-deleted.*

Comment: there's no requirement to "call a function" in the question

Comment: That's an an answer to the question "how do you swap without a temporary?", not this question.